# How to add custom row on the end of the table (b-table)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I need to add custom row ( different from rows before) to my grid b-table at the end. How can I do that? I have grid with 
Items | Amounts | Price 
and in last row i need to count total_amount and total_price of items.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-table
                striped hover :busy="isBusy" :fields="fields" :items="items" :show-empty="true"
                :empty-text="'Nebyly nalezeny žádné záznamy'" class="mb-0"
        >

            <template slot="name" slot-scope="data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control w-100" size="sm" v-model.lazy="data.item.name">
                    </b-form-input>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template slot="unit_price" slot-scope="data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b-form-input type="number" class="form-control w-100" size="sm" v-model.number="data.item.unit_price" @change="updatePriceTogether(data.item)">
                    </b-form-input>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template slot="amount" slot-scope="data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b-form-input type="number" class="form-control w-100" size="sm" v-model.number="data.item.amount" @change="updatePriceTogether(data.item)">
                    </b-form-input>
                </div>
            </template>

            <div slot="table-busy" class="text-center text-danger my-2">
                <b-spinner class="align-middle"></b-spinner>
                <strong>Načítání...</strong>
            </div>
            <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
                <slot name="action-buttons" :data="data"></slot>
            </template>

        </b-table>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "CustomItemGrid",
        props: {
            isBusy: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true
            },
            fields: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            items: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updatePriceTogether(item){
                item.total_price = (item.unit_price * item.amount).toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So i need something like this:

```
Item_name | Price | Amount | total_ price

Item1     | 12€     | 123  | 1400€

Item2     | 12€     | 123  | 1400€

**EMPTY     | Total:  | XXX T| XXXX€**
```

how can I add last row (It has to be always on bottom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities on how you could achieve this:

- Using the `footer` slot.
- Using a computed property to append an extra item to your `items` array which will represent your custom row.

## Using the `footer` slot

You can check [Buefy's documentation for the table component](https://buefy.org/documentation/table) in the "Footer" section (I'm unable to link it directly).

```
<template slot="footer">
  <!-- Your custom last row goes here -->
</template>
```

## Computed array with extra item

Add a computed property inside your component which returns the `items` array and appends an extra item.

```
computed: {
  itemsWithTotal() {
    return [
      ...this.items,
      { /* data for your last row */ }
    ];
  }
}
```

Remember to change the `items` prop of `b-table` to the new computed property. You will also have to differentiate between regular items and your custom last row item inside the column templates.

I'd recommend using the `footer` slot as you can avoid mixing your items array with a custom extra item.

Comment: Hi! have you tried using sticky footer in a b-table component? I don't know how to do it, I've tried changing css but not working for now

Comment: Judging by Buefy's documentation of the Table component it only supports a sticky header and columns natively:
https://buefy.org/documentation/table/#sticky-headers-and-columns

Perhaps you could take a look at how the sticky header is implemented and try to implement it on your own for the footer?